Tangle hypothesis and ribbon category
The tangle hypothesis, when specialized to ordinary framed tangles, says that the framed tangles form the free braided category with all duals (i.e. considered as a 3-category, all the 1- and 2-morphisms have adjoints) on one object. Another characterization of framed tangles is by ribbon categories. This seems to suggest that a ribbon category is the same as a braided category with all duals. Is this true?
If this is so, then since having adjoints is a property, the twist in the definition of ribbon categories must be unique, because there can't be more data here. Either this is secretly the case (which is pretty surprising), or the two concepts are different. It should furthermore imply that the ribbon element in ribbon hopf algebras act in the same way on all the finite-dimensional representations, which is most probably not true... Is there a proof or reference confirming either of these? If the latter, is there an equivalent definition of a braided category with all duals, removing all the redundant components and translated to purely 1-categorical terms? This should be an alternative way to create Reshetikhin–Turaev knot invariants.

The nLab (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ribbon+category) says that the free ribbon category on one object is the category of "framed oriented tangles." I don't know exactly what that means but presumably that "oriented" is where the ribbon element is coming from.

@QiaochuYuan Everything is assumed to be already oriented here, so it should be the same.

I'm not that familiar with the tangle hypothesis. What do you mean when you say "with all duals"? What is certainly true is that for a braided pivotal category (ie having left and right rigid structures, and both left and right duals coincide as monoidal functors), being ribbon is a property, not a structure (hence the twist is unique if it exists), because you can construct a left and right twists (namely the positive kink with a (counter)clock-wise rotation. If they coincide, then this is the (unique) twist.

You're confused about the statement of the tangle hypothesis. Lurie defines a ribbon $(\infty,1)$-category as a $\textrm{BSO}(3)$ homotopy fixpoint in the space of rigid braided monoidal $(\infty, 1)$-categories. This not only records all the tangles, but also the space of isotopies between tangles. If we truncate down to $1$-categories, then we should have an equivalence between ribbon categories and a $\textrm{BSO}(3)$ homotopy fixpoint in the space of rigid braided monoidal categories. Let's unpack what this means.
We first need to know what $\textrm{BSO}(3)$ is, and how it acts on rigid braided monoidal categories. Fortunately this is simple, since it is acting on a 2-groupoid, so we only need to understand the first two homotopy levels. $\pi_1(\textrm{SO}(3)) = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ and $\pi_2(\textrm{SO}(3)) = 0$. Therefore there is only one non-trivial homotopy groups, and we're effectively considering the action of $K(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z, 2)$. Unpacking this, we have a pseudonatural transformation $\tau : \textrm{Id} \to \textrm{Id}$, where $\textrm{Id}$ is the identity pseudofunctor on the 2-groupoid of rigid braided monoidal categories, and we have an isomorphism $\kappa : \tau^2 \cong \textrm{id}$. This isomorphism satisfies some equations which we don't need to care about.
$\tau$ is essentially a monoidal endofunctor on every rigid braided monoidal category. It turns out that $\tau$ sends an object $X$ to $X^{\vee \vee}$ (the other components of $\tau$ should be obvious). For braided rigid categories, $\tau$ is naturally isomorphic to the identity functor, given by a Reidemeister I loop $$
X
\xrightarrow{X \otimes \text{coev}(X^\vee)}
X \otimes X^{\vee \vee} \otimes X^\vee
\xrightarrow{\beta \otimes X^\vee}
X^{\vee \vee} \otimes X \otimes X^\vee
\xrightarrow{X^{\vee \vee} \otimes \text{ev}(X)}
X^{\vee\vee}.$$ However, this isomorphism is not monoidal. This is essentially saying that if you cut this ribbon in Reidemeister I configuration into two, then the two ribbons will be tangled.
However we have an isomorphism $\kappa : \tau^2 \cong \textrm{id}$, which means there is a monoidal natural isomorphism $X \cong X^{\vee\vee\vee\vee}$. This is because we can use the aforementioned map to go from $X$ to $X^{\vee\vee}$, and then go to $X^{\vee\vee\vee\vee}$ in a similar way, but we replace $\beta$ by $\beta^{-1}$. Now if you cut the ribbon in half again, you can cleanly separate them into two copies in the same configuration side by side.
Now we need to figure out what "homotopy fixpoint" means in this concrete context. We need, of course, a rigid braided category $\mathcal{C}$. We need to witness that $\tau$ acts trivially on $\mathcal{C}$, by providing a monoidal natural isomorphism $i : \tau_{\mathcal{C}} \cong \mathrm{Id}_{\mathcal{C}}$. (It needs to be monoidal since we are working in the 2-groupoid of rigid braided categories, and in it the 2-paths are monoidal natural isomorphisms.) This is exactly the data of a pivot. In the braided case, a pivot is the same amount of data as a balancing $\theta$. So we just need the additional equation $\theta_{X^\vee} = \theta_X^\vee$ to get a ribbon category.
We also need to know $\kappa$ acts trivially too. This essentially says that if you transfer $\kappa : \tau^2 \cong \textrm{id}$ across the isomorphism $i$, you will get the identity map $\textrm{Id}_{\mathcal C} \to \textrm{Id}_{\mathcal C}$. Re-expressing this in terms of the twist, you will get exactly $\theta_{X^\vee} = \theta_X^\vee$, granting us a ribbon category. See this paper for a survey of the definitions and calculations involved on the 1-categorical side of things.
What's nice about the higher categorical definition is that we can now produce Reshetikhin–Turaev 2-invariants effortlessly. Since $\pi_3 (\textrm{SO}(3)) = \mathbb Z$, there will be further non-trivial coherences.

When you write "you" here, are you addressing yourself?

@SamHopkins Yes, past me was pretty confused about things in general
